# getting Kendo Grid working

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I've simplified this to its barebones - pulled out any properties that might be interfering (I can put em back in if you like) - even pointing it at local .json - and still getting no data in my grid.

I did see data in the sample that I dropped in, when it was pointing at the Northwind api, so I know I've got my i's crossed and t's dotted.

```
        <div id="grid"></div>
```

This is in my controller:

```
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                type: "odata",
                transport: {
                    read: 'Content/data/Listings.json'
                }
             },
            height: 550,
           columns: [{
                field: "Id",
                title: "Id",
                width: 240  
            },{
                field: "State",
                title: "State",
                width: 240  
            }]
        });
```

The call it makes is this (I have no control over this):

```
http://localhost/Wizmo-web/Content/data/Listings.json?$callback=jQuery112103831734413679999_1470962161424&"%"24inlinecount=allpages&"%"24format=json
```

It **is** returning data from my Listings.json (which I've ensured is valid):

```
[
   {
      "Id":557,
      "State":"active",
      "Title":"Matching Father Son Shirts I Am Your Father Shirt ",
   },
   {
      "Id":558,
      "State":"active",
      "Title":"Baseball Hoodies Im All About That Base Hooded Swe",
   }
]
```

But my grid is empty.
No errors, no nothing.

Stumped.

Answer (score 0):

I looks like in your controller, you are trying to use the jQuery implementation of Kendo, instead of the supported Angular directives.

> The Kendo UI grid features inherent integration with AngularJS using directives which are officially supported as part of the product. To make use of this integration, you need to reference the Angular scripts in your app and register the module incorporating the Kendo UI directives in the following way:

```
angular.module("myApp", [ "kendo.directives" ])
```

So in your controller, instead of using jQuery `$("#grid").kendoGrid(...)` to find the element and add your config object, you are actually going to use a config object on your controller scope:

```
$scope.mainGridOptions = {
    //all your config options here
};
```

Then in your view, instead of using just `<div id="grid"></div>` you're actually going to use the Kendo directive here, and pass it the config object from your controller:

```
<kendo-grid options="mainGridOptions">
...
```

Kendo has some pretty good documentation on Angular implementation [here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/angular)

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you. And now my teeth won;t grind at embedding jQuery in my angular.

Comment: Set it up per your instructions and per angular documentation.
When I insert angular.module("WizmoApp", [ "kendo.directives" ]) my app dies silently. No errors, nothing.

Comment: Yes. I've ripped everything else out except kendo.directives and it just dies. My controller is literally 7 lines - including (function(){, use strict and })().

Comment: I've found one problem. I have a main app.js which contains angular     .module('WizmoApp', ['ngResource','ngSanitize', etc. so I"m pretty sure that's where I'm supposed to add 'kendo.directives'. By removing it from my controller, the page is no longer blank - though I still get no display of the Kendo-grid.

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle, or codepen with your code? Should be easy to fix from there.

Comment: I found this http://www.markschabacker.com/blog/2015/07/31/angular-service-as-kendo-datasource/
The read block seems to do the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem is different - the dataSource configuration includes a `type: "odata"` setting, which does not correspond to the server response, so it should be removed. With this setting, the Kendo UI DataSource instance is not able to find the data items in the returned JSON, that's why no table rows are rendered.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-type

Here is a runnable example without the `type` setting:

http://dojo.telerik.com/ESija

Comment: Thanks. ITICC is correct. I was using the jQuery implementation in my Angular app.

Answer (score 0):

The moment I add [ 'kendo.directives' ] to the module, everything dies. No errors, nothing.

Controller:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('WizmoApp', [ 'kendo.directives' ])
        .controller('listingsController', listingsController);

    listingsController.$inject = ['$http', '$location', '$stateParams', '$filter', 'toastr', 'DTOptionsBuilder', 'DTColumnDefBuilder', 'listingsService', 'datatableService', 'ngAuthSettings'];

    function listingsController($http, $location, $stateParams, $filter, toastr, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnDefBuilder, listingsService, datatableService, ngAuthSettings) {

...
```

index.html:

```
<script src="Content/vendor/Metronic/global/plugins/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
...
<script src="Content/vendor/Metronic/global/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Content/vendor/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Content/vendor/angular/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Content/vendor/KendoUI/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```